# Why does strpos return different results?

Tags: php, strpos, strtr

I have the following function that transforms special accent characters (like ă) into a-zA-Z characters in a string:

```
function tradu($sir){

        $sir_aux = $sir;

        $diacritice = array("ă"=>"a", "â"=>"a", "î"=>"i", "Î"=>"I", "ș"=>"s", "ş"=>"s", "ţ"=>"t", "ț"=>"t");

        for($i=0; $i<strlen($sir_aux); $i++){

            foreach($diacritice as $key=>$value){
                if($sir_aux[$i]==$key)
                    $sir_aux[$i]=$value;
            }
        }

        $sir_aux = strtr($sir, $diacritice);

        return $sir_aux;
    }
```

Let's say a is the original string and a_translated is the translated string.

**When I use `strpos(a, string_to_find)` and `strpos(a_translated, string_to_find)`, the returned values are different. I also checked `strlen(a)` and `strlen(a_translate)` and they give different results.**
*Why is this happening?*

**I need this explanation because** I need to search if a string with accents contains a given normal string (without accents), but I must return the portion from the original string where I found it even if it contains accents.

**What I tried**
I translate the original string and find the position where the searched_string starts, then I `substr(ORIGINAL_STRING, position)`. This is where I noticed the positions do not correspond.

*Example: 
ORIGINAL STRING: Universitatea a fost **înființată** în 2001 pentru a oferi...
SEARCHED STRING: infiintata
DESIRED RESULT: **înființată** în 2001 pentru a oferi...*

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @BartFriederichs strpos gives me different results when searching for a string (for example infiintata) inside a string containing accents and the same string but translated.  for example 234 and 265

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position you get from `strpos` is not correct, because your original string is multi-byte and `strpos` can't handle multibyte strings. Try [mb_strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) instead.

Try:

`mb_strpos(a,string_to_find,0,'UTF-8');`

and

`mb_strpos(a_translated,string_to_find,0,'UTF-8');`

you will see they have the same result.

See this code demonstrates the difference between strpos (which cant handle multi-byte strings) and mb_strpos:

```
$original_multibyte_string       = 'țată în  HERE';
$a_non_multibyte_str_same_length = '123456789HERE';
// HERE is on 10th (index 9 on array) character

echo 'strpos finds HERE in multibyte at: '.strpos($original_multibyte_string,'HERE').' '.'strpos finds HERE in non-multibyte at: '.strpos($a_non_multibyte_str_same_length,'HERE');
// OUTPUTS: strpos finds HERE in multibyte at: 12 strpos finds HERE in non-multibyte at: 9

echo "\n";
// now lets test the multibyte:

echo 'mb_strpos finds HERE in multibyte at: '.mb_strpos($original_multibyte_string,'HERE',0,'UTF-8').' '.'mb_strpos finds HERE in non-multibyte at: '.mb_strpos($a_non_multibyte_str_same_length,'HERE',0,'UTF-8');
// OUTPUTS: mb_strpos finds HERE in multibyte at: 9 mb_strpos finds HERE in non-multibyte at: 9
```

http://3v4l.org/ksYal

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, it worked! Have a beautiful day!

Answer (score 1):

It's because these functions are not supporting UTF8 characters.

a = 1 bit encoding
ă = 2 bit encoding

It's the answer!

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, and have a beautiful day!